# Suggestions required on radiation tolerance solutions

Tags: radiation, cubesat

I wanted to know what methods of increasing radiance tolerance for the microcontroller and memory devices for a Cubesat exist. We have read about methods like having dual CPUs but are there any recommendations while using of COTS components.
Also do you guys know of any other Radiation hardened microcontrollers apart from VA10820, ATMegaS128 and the MSP430FR5969.

Comment: I recommend breaking up the question into its two parts - discussion on rad hardening methods and specific inquiry on rad-hard microcontrollers.

Comment: @CarlosN agreed, and for each question, include results of a quick search of this site  for the parts that have already been answered. I think rad-hard electronics and cubesats may have been addressed in several posts already.

Comment: @PuneetShrivas it's a good question but much of it may have answers already. I'd say go ahead and take out part of this question and ask separately, but check existing questions and answers here first to make sure there isn't an obvious duplicate. *Welcome to Space!*

Comment: Add watchdog timers to reset the system after single event upsets.